# formatting data table in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, column-width

For my data table I have the following `ui.R` file:

```
tabItem(tabName = "maForwardVsSpot", fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "maForwardVsSpotTABLE"))
```

My `server.R` looks like this:

```
output$maForwardVsSpotTABLE <- DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable(dt.FvsS, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, class = 'cell-border stripe',
                    colnames = c("Date", "Spot", input$maStrategy, "Mean Difference"),
                    options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
                                   columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(0,1,2,3), width = '200px')),
                                   initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                                     "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#007d3c', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                                     "}")
                    )
      )
  
})
```

This results in the following data table, whereby the parts circled in red do not fit me, because they should start flush with the data table and not be far away from it to the left and right.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that. Did you try `class = 'display cell-border stripe'`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this already and it doesn't change anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
tabItem(
  tabName = "maForwardVsSpot", 
  tags$div(
    style = "width: fit-content;",
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "maForwardVsSpotTABLE")
  )
)
```